# asp.net - Parse string to XML in new Tab

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, parsing

I have a string in my model.The string is actually XML content.
I have a link on my page, when clicked it opens a new tab and displays the text as XML.

The result should be the same as when I right click on an xml file and open with Internet Explorer.
The difference is that this is no file, its text that I need to display as XML in a new tab.

Anyone have an idea how to achieve this without creating a file and without giving a path to a file.

Comment: Try to return FileResult from a controller action and set the mime type to xml. Not sure if it will work.

Comment: @user1702369 don't forget to accept as answer if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

You can write xml content directly to response like below. You can store your xml string in Session like:

```
Session["xmlContent"] = ...; //some xml content;
```

And then read it at redirected page:

```
string xmlContent = string.Empty;
if(Session["xmlContent"] != null)
    xmlContent = Session["xmlContent"].ToString();
```

It is how can you write xml string to your response at Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string xmlContent = GetXml();

    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/xml";
    Response.Write(xmlContent);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}

//This method simulates getting xml content. Of course your xml content can come from anywhere
private string GetXml()
{
    string xmlContent = "<note><to>You</to><from>Me</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>It should work for you</body></note>";
    return xmlContent;
}
```